# Betfair Non-Interactive (Bot) login doesn't work in Google App Engine region eu-west2 (London)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, betfair

The error I'm getting is BETTING_RESTRICTED_LOCATION. But when I run my app locally using London location from VPN I am able to login in perfectly.

Is there a way I can ensure that the app is running from places where betting is legal?

There is another question like this but its very old and doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

The IPs of Google Cloud Platform share the same geolocation (US). And it could be possible that your bot doesn't allow connections from this part of the world. If this is the issue, there isn't any available solution within GCP just yet. You can follow [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112448138) feature request or in the meantime, just point the requests to an on-prem service hosted in London that acts as a proxy.