# Outgoing HTTP Request Location on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

I have an API made with NodeJS (NodeJS v10 + Express v4.16 + Node-Fetch v2.3) and into this API, I have one endpoint that need to consume content from a third-party API/Service via HTTP Request (POST)

The problem is: This third-party API **only accepts** requests coming from **Brazil**

In the past, my API was hosted on Digital Ocean, but with this rule I have migrated to GCP (since DO doesn't have hosts in Brazil) and created my App Engine Application under region **southamerica-east1** (Sao Paulo/Brazil according with [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/?hl=pt-br) document)

*And yeah... It works on my machine ¯|_(ツ)_/¯*

What's happening: Sometimes the requests runs Ok, working fine, but after some version updates (I'm using CI/CD to make de deployment) the requests goes down.

The Question: Exist a way to control my application to only use the hosted region to make the outgoing requests??

PS* I'm not using flex env, purposely to prevent auto-scale (and cost elevation). (I don't know if I'm right about it because I'm new on GCP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPs of Google Cloud Platform share the same geolocation (US) so I would say that it's expected for the requests to fail. You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829340/my-google-app-instances-does-not-seem-to-be-on-correct-region#) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041348/betfair-non-interactive-bot-login-doesnt-work-in-google-app-engine-region-eu/58043703#58043703) questions for more info and potential workarounds.